# Load an existing record in a form that has a macro to load (blank) as new

Tags: vba, ms-access

Scenario: blank form (let's call this Form B) in Microsoft Access 2016 that has a macro that causes the form to be blank (new record) on load; however, I would also like to implement a button that causes a record that is selected on a different form (Form A) to load on Form B.

The logic is Form A is populated with a record selected from a list box. The user cannot modify this record as it appears on Form A (controls are locked); however, the list box containing the list of records is populated from a dynamic search query. If the user does not find the appropriate record, the user clicks a button to open Form B, which allows the user to enter a new record. Once that record is entered, the user can now use the search box to find the newly entered record.

If the user selects a record and notices that the record needs to be edited due to incorrect data, I would like to implement a button that the user can click to load the record in Form A into Form B to be edited.

I have no clue how I would do this programmatically in VBA, but the pseudo code would sort of look like this:

Private Sub

Upon edit_record_button click, set Form B to not load 'Go to new record'

Load Form B with current record from Form A

End Sub

Please see my code below: I think the '#' is ruining the code (bad attribute design):

```
Private Sub Command438_Click()
If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Escort",,,WhereCondition:="Credential # = " & Me!Credential #
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is remove the code and part that jumps the form to a new record all nice and ready to enter a new reocrd.

Your idea and goal of having duel use (same form to add, or to edit existing) of course makes sense - you want duel use of the form here.

The way you do this?
Now, to open the form in add mode, you do this:

```
 docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomers",,,,acFormAdd
```

So that will launch the form in add mode - on a fresh blank reocrd.

But, to edit existing, say prompting user for customer number

```
 dim strCustNo    as string
 strCustNo = Inputbox("Enter customer number")
 docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomers",,,"ID = " & strCustNo
```

So, that would open the form to the one given customer number.

Or, you could open the form to edit all records like this:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomers"
```

So, the trick is remove that code and stuff that jumps the form to the new blank record, and then in the code that opens/launches the form you control if you editing all records, opening in add mode, or even jumping to and editing one record.

I also suggest you set in the property sheet other table the forms cycle property to the current record - since if you are on the last control/field on the form and hit tab, you can wind up jumping to a new blank record, and in most cases you do not want this.

And you can even turn off the allow additions property of the form, and the above open in add mode will ONLY allow adding of one record - and this again can often be a nice UI choice to toss up a form, let user add one record, and then they close the form. Regardless, the main trick and idea here is that by choosing HOW you open the form, then you can control if you are adding a record, or editing records - and you don't need or have special code in the form when loading to always JUMP to a new blank record (so remove that code/part) and control this action by using the features of the openFrom command.

## Edit

It has been pointed out that the above "ID" example is poor. Yes, it was/is some air code, and one would in most cases avoid even using input box.

If you were on say a nice details form like this:

[image]

Or even a form displaying a single record?

Then to launch the form to the one record, you would use this:

```
if  me.Dirty = true then me.Dirty = false   ' optional if editing can occur

docmd.Openfrom  "frmDetailsEdit",,,"ID = " & ME!ID
```

Comment: Ah. The user, however, would have to know the customer number. I have concealed the private key value from the user, thus I would have to add a control to reveal this ID to the user. I wonder if there is a way to simply cause the form to open based on the record that is in Form A without an input box.

Comment: Sure, that was "air code". Better example but the SAME idea would be invoice number etc. So, yes, you most certainly would build some kind of user interface as opposed to a VERY LAME inputbox() command.  You would build a nice search form like this:http://www.kallal.ca/Search/index.html

Comment: See my edit above. You can of course use the internal PK "id" for this, but of course the user would search and work with invoice number, company name etc. So, in actual practice one would never prompt or use the hidden PK name.

Comment: For some reason, the code in the first example is not working. Also, second example code is not working, but I think it is my attribute name.

Comment: Also, I have my Form B set to new record on load using a macro. So, the record will not load. Also, I don't have a subform data table to select records. I have a list box (I imagine that complicates things a little bit).

Comment: Well, using a simple inputbox, a cool looking sub form, a combo box, or just about any thing else you  can cook and dream up? Makes no difference here. the simple and basic suggestion here is to remove that offending code that jumps to a new record, and control this action by use of the options you have when using the OpenForm command. So, really, no matter what approach you use? when you launch that 2nd form, use the correct options in the OpenForm command to edit a record. Or edit all records. Or load +j ump to edit a single record, or open the form in "add" mode.

Comment: So, I am rather lost as to why this approach would not work for you.